# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^m\sin^2\left(n\frac\pi{m}\right)=\frac{m}2$ for $m\geq 2$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, induction

> $$\sum_{n=1}^m \sin^2\left(n\frac{\pi}{m}\right) = \frac{m}{2}$$ for all $m\ge2$ positive integers

I'm doing a maths problem that involves proving by mathematical induction the sum of a sigma. I find it hard because the highest term is included in the sigma so it changes the actual sigma.

If anyone can help me, please respond it would be very useful!! Even just the smallest help will go a long way : )

Here is the [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4dtemulxvj) to show you this is true.

But I want to prove it using induction.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's true, but to show that with induction (over $m$?!) is an... interesting idea. You'll find the fact that $m$ is in the denominator of a fraction... difficult.

Comment: It's easier to prove this without using induction over $m$. But if you really need a proof using induction, then you should begin with a more general form $$f(m,\color{red}x)=\sum_{n=1}^m \sin^2\left(n\frac{\pi}{m}\color{red}x\right)$$ And you find $f(m,\color{red}x)$ by induction.
$$f(m+1,x) = f(m,\frac{m}{m+1}x) + \sin^2(..)$$

Comment: @NN2 Could it be that you meant $f(m,\color{red}x)=\sum_{n=1}^m \sin^2\left(n\color{red}x\right)$?

Comment: @qfwfq  I really meant $f(m,x) =  \sum \sin^2 (n \pi /m x)$. But it seems to me that your formula works too.

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS**

Write $$\sin^2(n \pi /m)= \frac{1 - \cos(2 n \pi/m)}{2}.$$
Then by the linearity of finite sums, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \sin^2(n \pi /m) = \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1 - \cos(2 n \pi/m)}{2}=\frac{m}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos(2n \pi/m)}{2},$$ which is almost the answer.

You can now show that $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos(2n \pi/m)}{2}=0$ for $m \ge 2$ by an induction argument or by noticing it is the real part of the finite geometric series $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^m e^{2 \pi i n/m}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I like the idea of showing the second sigma to be equal to 0. Im trying it now. However, it is a similar problem because the denominator changes which changes the sigma and I can't cancel or substitute. Could you maybe guide me into solving induction for equal to 0?

Comment: Hmm .. now that I think about it, induction is not as easy compared to the complex analytic direct proof. I don't have a clear idea. Assume the inductive hypothesis holds for some $m \ge 2.$ My try was to look at the difference $\sum_{n=1}^{m+1} \cos(2 \pi n/(m+1)) - \sum_{n=1}^{m} \cos(2 \pi n/(m))= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^m \cos(2 \pi n/(m+1))-\cos(2 \pi n/(m)).$ The series term in the latter inequality should equal $-1$ and my intuition tells me it is a telescoping series ..

Comment: My problem is, I cancel out terms but I am left with one term. For example, if I used your method of proving the sigma to be equal to 0, I cancel the two terms and im left with 1/2 cos(4π/k) which doesn't equal zero. Have you attempted to solve for induction and has it worked for you in any way?? Thanks for your time.

Comment: No I haven't quite gotten around to it. I will let you know if/when I do.

Comment: Thank you for your time, no rush : )

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess I found a proof without using induction. Perhaps it will be of any use to you so I will leave it here.
$$\sin\varphi=\frac{e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi}}{2i}$$
Let $\varphi_n=\frac{n\pi}{m}$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m}\sin^2{\varphi_n}=\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac{e^{i\varphi_n}-e^{-i\varphi_n}}{2i}\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{e^{2i\varphi_n}+e^{-2i\varphi_n}-2}{-4}=\frac{m}{2}-\left(\sum_{n=1}^me^{2i\varphi_n} +\sum_{n=1}^me^{-2i\varphi_n}\right)=\frac{m}{2}-\left(\sum_{n=1}^me^{2i\frac{n\pi}{m}} +\sum_{n=1}^me^{-2i\frac{n\pi}{m}}\right)=\frac{m}{2}-\left( \frac{e^{2\pi i}-1}{e^\frac{2\pi i}{n}-1}+\frac{e^{-2\pi i}-1}{e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{n}}-1}\right)=\frac{m}{2}-\left( \frac{1-1}{e^\frac{2\pi i}{n}-1}+\frac{1-1}{e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{n}}-1}\right)=\frac{m}{2}$$

Comment: Hello! Could you maybe explain how you equated  the sigma to the fraction? Im not sure what you did there... Thanks.

Comment: I used the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, i.e. $$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: Wow very smart! Thank you for your time, you have helped me so much.