# Why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\sin^2\left((2k-1)\frac\pi n\right)=\frac n4$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I found the relation for $n\geq3$ $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\sin^2\left((2k-1)\frac\pi n\right)=\frac n4$$But despite my best efforts, I still have no idea as to how to prove it.

Things I've tried:

1. Adding $\cos^2$ terms. Of course, $\sin^2x+\cos^2x$ and $\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ are both simplifiable, so I thought about adding $\cos^2$ terms to make the sum into $\frac n2$ and hope that the $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ terms sum to equal amounts. They don't in the $n$ odd case, so I didn't know what to do with this approach.
2. Adding more $\sin^2$ terms: Since $\sin^2 x=\sin^2(\pi-x)$, we can add terms to this sum, but honestly, it didn't make the sum any easier to evaluate.

Any help here?

Edit:

Based on the comments, here are my attempts.

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\sin^2\left((2k-1)\frac\pi n\right)=\frac12\cdot\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor-\frac12\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\cos\left((2k-1)\frac{2\pi}n\right)$$$$=\frac12\cdot\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor-\frac12\mathfrak{Re}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{2i\pi}n\right)\right)$$How do I finish?

Comment: Perhaps the identity
$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$
Will be of use

Comment: Here is something similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4055466/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Ah my question is a duplicate. Whoops.

Comment: @DonThousand Doesn't look like a verbatim duplicate to me...

Comment: @TheBestMagician Still struggling a bit: I'm editing with my attempts

Comment: That looks good. Take cases on the parity of $n$. If $n$ is even, we want to prove that that $\mathrm{exp}$ summand is $0$. Try possibly matching terms?

Comment: @TheBestMagician In the $n$ even case, I'm trying to pair the $k$th summand with the $\left(\frac n2-k+1\right)$th summand, but since $\cos$ is an even function, they just turn out to be equal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your way, by geometric series we have that for $n=2N$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{2i\pi}n\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{i\pi}N\right)=\\=e^{-\frac{i\pi }N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\left(e^{\frac{i2\pi}N}\right)^k=e^{-\frac{i\pi }N}\frac{e^{\frac{i2\pi}N}-e^{\frac{i2\pi(N+1)}N}}{1-e^{\frac{i2\pi}N}}=e^{\frac{i\pi }N}\frac{1-e^{i2\pi}}{1-e^{\frac{i2\pi}N}}=0$$

then

$$\frac12\cdot\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor-\frac12\mathfrak{Re}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{2i\pi}n\right)\right)=\frac12 N+0 = \frac n 4$$

For $n=2N+1$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{2i\pi}n\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{i\pi}{2N+1}\right)=\\
=e^{-\frac{i2\pi }{2N+1}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\left(e^{\frac{i4\pi}{2N+1}}\right)^k
=e^{-\frac{i2\pi }{2N+1}}\frac{e^{\frac{i4\pi}{2N+1}}-e^{\frac{i4\pi(N+1)}{2N+1}}}{1-e^{\frac{i4\pi}{2N+1}}}
=\frac{e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}-1}{1-e^{\frac{i4\pi}{2N+1}}}=-\frac1{1+e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}}$$

and we also have

$$w=-\frac1{1+e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}} \implies w+\bar w=-1 \implies \Re(w)=-\frac12$$

indeed

$$w+\bar w=-\frac1{1+e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}}-\frac1{1+e^{\frac{-i2\pi}{2N+1}}}=-\frac1{1+e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}}-\frac{e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}}{1+e^{\frac{i2\pi}{2N+1}}}=-1$$

then

$$\frac12\cdot\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor-\frac12\mathfrak{Re}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\exp\left((2k-1)\frac{2i\pi}n\right)\right)=\frac12 N+\frac14 = \frac{2N+1}{4}=\frac n 4$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but why is the conjugate of $1+e^{\frac{2i\pi}{2N+1}}$: $1+e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{2n+1}}$?

Comment: @DonThousand The conjugate can be obtained switching the $i's$ in $-i's$.

Comment: Ah I'm just having a mental block, thanks for resolving that.

Comment: @DonThousand You are welcome! This is the way I also thought at the first sight! Bye

Answer (score 4):

Let$$T=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\cos\left((2k-1)\frac{2\pi} n\right)$$$$S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\sin^2\left((2k-1)\frac\pi n\right)$$
We can get the relation $T+2S=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$

---

If $n$ is even then using summation of cosines whose angles are in AP we get,
$$T=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\cos\left((2k-1)\frac{2\pi} n\right)=\frac {\sin\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor\frac {2\pi}n}{\sin\frac {2\pi}n}\cos\bigg[\frac{2\pi}n+(\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor-1)\frac{2\pi}n\bigg]=0$$
$$\implies S=\frac n4$$

---

If $n$ is odd then let $n=2m+1$. We get,
$$\begin{align*}T=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\cos\left((2k-1)\frac{2\pi} {2m+1}\right)&=\frac {\sin \frac {2\pi m}{2m+1}}{\sin\frac {2\pi}{2m+1}}\cos\bigg[\frac{2\pi}{2m+1}+(m-1)\frac{2\pi}{2m+1}\bigg]
\\&
\\&=\frac {\sin \frac {2\pi m}{2m+1}\cos \frac {2\pi m}{2m+1}}{\sin\frac {2\pi}{2m+1}}
\\&
\\&=\frac {\sin \frac {4\pi m}{2m+1}}{2\sin\frac {2\pi}{2m+1}}
\\&
\\&=\frac {-\sin \frac {2\pi }{2m+1}}{2\sin\frac {2\pi}{2m+1}}=\frac{-1}{2}\end{align*}$$
$$\implies S=\frac{2m+1}2=\frac n4$$